# How to use Ramda remove to remove empty object from Array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

**[Ramda remove](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#remove)** : [Ramda Repl link](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?var%20objArray%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Leon%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Paulo%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0A%2F%2FR.remove%282%2C%203%2C%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B1%2C2%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D%0A%0A%2F%2FR.remove%28%7B%7D%2C%20objArray%29%3B%0AR.remove%28R.isEmpty%2C%20objArray%29%3B%0A%0A)

The following is the given example, it removes specific numbers from an Array:

`R.remove(2, 3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); //=> [1,2,6,7,8]`

Now I created an Array of objects, one being empty:

```
var objArray = [{id: 1, name: 'Leon'},{id: 2, name: 'Paulo'},{}];
```

When I try:

`R.remove({}, objArray);`

or

`R.remove(R.isEmpty, objArray);`

It returns a function:

[image]

Why would that be you suppose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out:

`const filteredAlerts = R.filter(Util.notEmpty, res.alerts);`

I needed to filter by objects that are NOT empty.

This is my `Util.notEmpty` function:

`const notEmpty = R.compose(R.not, R.isEmpty);`

Comment: A nicer way to define `notEmpty` is `R.complement(R.isEmpty)`. Better yet one could use `R.reject` rather than `R.filter`. The expression would then become `R.reject(R.isEmpty, res.alerts)` with no need for a helper function. :)

Comment: @LeonGaban, regarding ramda stuff, [davidchambers](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/graphs/contributors) is gonna be your go-to guy

Comment: @naomik thanks! Starting following him now, love Ramda :)